# Get exact result for number division

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

`SELECT 9/2` gives `4`

Why gives postgresql automatically rounded result?

There are some option for prevent this? (That is, I need that after division, if result is float, returns exactly and not rounded result).

**UPDATE**:

for example from function, I need return floating number

```
       CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION division_test (arg1 INTEGER, arg2 INTEGER,) RETURNS NUMERIC
        AS $$
            BEGIN
            RETURN arg1 / arg2;
            END;
        $$
        LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

`SELECT division_test (9,2)`

result: 4

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without having tried it, would `SELECT 9.0/2.0` help you?

**As an answer to the edited question:**

Would changing the datatype in the argument help?

```
       CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION division_test (arg1 REAL, arg2 REAL) RETURNS REAL
        AS $$
            BEGIN
            RETURN arg1 / arg2;
            END;
        $$
        LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Or depending on your required precision, you could also use `NUMERIC` or another fitting [numeric type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/datatype.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC).

Comment: @OTARIKI: Because both input arguments are integers, the result will be cast to an integer as well, giving you a "rounded" result. When changing the type of the input parameter to `real` the result of the division is also a `real`.

Comment: As pointed out, it has to do with the input params to the division operation.  But, just to be clear, it doesn't have to be a function.  Same thing works with typecasting a select.  Such as: `SELECT (9/2) as int_value, (9::real/2::real), (9::numeric/2::numeric) as numeric_value;`

Answer (score 2):

One option multiply or divide by 1.0, the result will be a decimal.

> ```
> psql (9.4.5)
> Type "help" for help.
>
> tabd=# select 1 / 10;  
> ----------
>     0 (1 row)
>
> tabd=# select 1.0 * 1 / 10;    
> ------------------------
>  0.10000000000000000000 (1 row)
> ```