# Why does my query involving division and COUNT always result in 1?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've simplified this down a bit since the literal data is pretty massive but a very simple example will suffice. I'm working on a query where because of the massive amount of data, I'm looking to do some aggregation in one shot instead of many many steps.

I have two tables

```
<<customers>>
id | first_name | last_name
1  | Reed       | Richards
2  | Johnny     | Storm
3  | Peter      | Parker

<<purchases>>
id | cid | date
1  | 1   | 2017-01-09
2  | 2   | 2017-01-09
3  | 2   | 2017-01-09
4  | 3   | 2017-01-09
```

When I run the query

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(c.id) as "Total Customers",
    COUNT(p.id) as "Total Sales",
    COUNT(c.id)/COUNT(p.id) as "Sales per customer"
FROM test_customers c
    LEFT OUTER JOIN test_purchases p ON c.id = p.cid
```

I get

```
4 | 4 | 1
```

When I'm looking for ...

```
3 | 4 | 1.3333333...
```

This example is extremely simplified, but the real case of this is massively larger. I'm sure there's a way to do this, I'm just not sure what that is right now.

Comment: Look up how to convert data to decimals/floats.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get exact result for number division](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16963926/get-exact-result-for-number-division)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16963926/get-exact-result-for-number-division also look at using ::float

Comment: This post could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10271548/how-to-convert-integer-to-decimal-in-sql-server-query

Comment: Y'all are focusing on the datatype when the underlying query is off...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to count distinct rows, but not using a `count(distinct ...)`

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(distinct c.id) as "Total Customers",
    COUNT(distinct p.id) as "Total Sales",
    COUNT(distinct c.id) * 1.00 / COUNT(distinct p.id) as "Sales per customer"
FROM test_customers c
    LEFT OUTER JOIN test_purchases p ON c.id = p.cid
```

Note, performance is not great

Comment: You will need to cast the `count()` to a `decimal` otherwise this won't return any fractional values